# How does pandas identify the target column in boolean indexing?

Tags: python, pandas

`df[df["A"] > 0]`

This is boolean indexing. The `df["A"] > 0` returns boolean values.

Say the dataframe has multiple columns: A, B, C

Now when the boolean values are applied to the df using `df[....]`, then how does pandas know that the boolean indexing has to be applied column A?

Comment: It's not applied to column A ... you are filtering the whole dataframe like this

Comment: What do you mean by filter whole df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question,

> The `df["A"] > 0` returns boolean values.

`df[boolean_array]` will simply return indexes of `df` in which `boolean_array` contains `True`. All the heavy lifting is done by `df["A"] > 0` in which it is pretty clear how it "knows" which column to reference .